# HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable in appengine python "guestbook" app

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am running the demo python guestbook app on Google AppEngine Python SDK but its giving such error on browser. I have not changed any single line of code in script file.

I am using Python version 2.7.10
Google Python SDK version "GoogleAppEngine-1.9.28.exe"
and Webapp2 Framework.

The error:

```
the runtime process gave a bad HTTP response: ''

WARNING  2015-11-17 08:29:59,892 tasklets.py:410] suspended generator run_to_queue(query.py:938) raised HTTPError(HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable)
WARNING  2015-11-17 08:29:59,894 tasklets.py:410] suspended generator helper(context.py:876) raised HTTPError(HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable)
ERROR    2015-11-17 08:29:59,894 webapp2.py:1552] HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\abhilash singh\Documents\guestbook\guestbook.py", line 42, in get
    for greeting in greetings:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\query.py", line 1774, in next
    self._more_results) = self._fut.get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\tasklets.py", line 326, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\context.py", line 876, in helper
    batch, i, ent = yield inq.getq()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\query.py", line 938, in run_to_queue
    batch = yield rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\tasklets.py", line 455, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_query.py", line 2907, in __query_result_hook
    self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastore\datastore_rpc.py", line 1371, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 579, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 201, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 227, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What command are you running that is failing? According to the stacktrace you provided, it appears that you are using the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) to connect to a deployed application and query over the Datastore entities. If you have not yet deployed an app to App Engine's servers, this command will not succeed, and it may very well result in the 503 error that you've shared.

Comment: I am using google appengine python SDK local server for practise and running apps locally